# Redirect desktop site to mobile using window.location.href and matching arrays of URLs (one for desktop one for mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, mobile

Client has two websites: desktop and mobile (don't ask why desktop isn't responsive).

Desktop site has many pages that are actually just anchors within a page.  E.g. aboutus.html#team that now has to redirect to team.html when someone is viewing on a small mobile device.  And all mobile pages have different names than desktop pages (aboutus.html = about-us.html).

Rather than put code on every single page to redirect that individual page (which leaves no way to redirect the anchored URLs) it's been suggested to use an array for the desktopURLs and a related array for the mobileURLs.

So (note I omitted the // after http: so they don't show up as links since I don't have enough points to post links):

```
var desktopURL = ['http:domain.com/aboutus.html','http:domain.com/aboutus.html#/team','http:domain.com/contactus.html']
var mobileURL = ['http:m.domain.com/about-us.html','http:m.domain.com/team.html','http:m.domain.com/contact-us.html']
```

Once I have that set up, where desktopURL index 1 = mobileURL index 1.

I need to basically say this in code:

```
Get the window.location.href and look it up in desktopURL and return the index value.

Once you have the index value of desktopURL for the current window, update window.location.href with the object of the matching index number from the mobileURL array.
```

So that, when I'm a person on a phone and I go to domain.com/aboutus.html I am automatically redirected to m.domain.com/about-us.html

Note that I cannot change the names of any of the pages on the mobile site (making them match the original site would have made this easy).  So I need to figure out a code way to do this and I have researched extensively but am just not sure how to achieve this simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the JS:

```
var desktopURL = ['aboutus.html','aboutus.html#team','contactus.html']
var mobileURL = ['about-us.html','team.html','contact-us.html']

//Get the name of current page
var currPage=(window.location.href).split("/")[(window.location.href).split("/").length-1];
console.log(currPage);
var index=desktopURL.indexOf(currPage);
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
window.location.href=mobileURL[index];
```

}

Check redirecttest[dot]webuda[dot]com

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to accomplish is better handled with an object lookup. Managing two arrays, as you have suggested, is very fragile solution (no real relationship exists there, which will make it difficult to scale/maintain).

```
var MOBILE_ROOT = 'm.domain.com';
var LOOKUP = {
   '/aboutus.html':       '/about-us.html',
   '/aboutus.html#/team': '/team.html',
   '/contactus.html':     '/contact-us.html'
};

function redirect () {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    window.location.href = MOBILE_ROOT + LOOKUP[ path + hash ];
}

...

if ( //user agent lookup goes here ) {
    redirect();
}
```